# How to deconvolve normally distributed errors

Tags: probability, distributions, error, measurement-error, convolution

I have a random variable which is has some unknown distribution (I have some priors for what it may be but the less assumptions the better). I'm then measuring it with some normally distributed error in those measurements where I know the standard deviation of that. My hope is that there is a good way to remove that measurement error to get some idea of the actual underlying distribution.

ie my variable is something of the form: $Y = X + e$ where $e ~N(0,\sigma^2)$ and I'm trying to find the distribution of X.

I've found a couple of papers which discuss ways to do this however they're ending up flying over my head math wise:

https://www.jstor.org/stable/2965416?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents

The only thing that I've thought of was to generate the empirical pdf of the data and then explicitly deconvolve that with the kernel of a normal function, however I feel like that although that will probably work that it is not the 'correct' way to do this...

Comment: Deconvolution of the empirical distribution with literally any continuous error distribution will produce a function that is not a distribution.  Deconvolution in general tends to be unstable.  Unless you have a great deal of data, you are usually best off exploiting your knowledge and assumptions about the underlying distribution.

Comment: @whuber Specifically I expect in the cases that it will matter that the underlying distribution is a shifted exponential and I'm trying to estimate the shift. Additionally what do you mean by unstable? (just in terms of it doesn't converge with more data?)

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a procedure to *estimate* the parameters of that exponential and your model is one that is solved with *nonlinear least squares.*  By "unstable" I mean extremely sensitive to small changes in the data and the parameter $\sigma.$